# Possible vulnerabilities in cookie set

Tags: http, security

So i have a subdomain, that everytime someone access to it, it will redirect the person to a login subdomain and making the entire path submited after the subdomain be a cookie set before making the redirect, without any sanitize. For example:

Subdomain access: **sub.domain.com/some/path**

Creating cookie header response: **Set-Cookie: save_path=some/path; Domain=sub.domain.com; Path=/**;

Could this leave space to any kind of vulnerability, even if i sanitize the string properly when i access to it or display it if necessary?

Thanks for the help.